# Creating Second Workspace

Tags: catkin, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a workspace called "catkin_ws" in my home directory. I built the workspace with the command `catkin_make` and  I added two extra lines to .bashrc file:

`source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash`

`source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`

Then, I created second workspace called "catkin_ws2" in my home directory and built it by using the command `catkin_make`. Finally, I decided to delete second workspace by using the command `catkin clean`. However, when I try to delete it with that command, the message `current or desired workspace could not be determined` is displayed.

Why cannot I delete it ? (Note: I execute `catkin clean` in the directory ~/catkin_ws2)

My opinion: Since I did not source setup.bash file of second workspace, catkin build tool does not know such a workspace exists.Hence, the command does not work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327760/creating-second-workspace/) by [gktg1514](https://answers.ros.org/users/37700/gktg1514/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2019-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here I think that should be helpful.

http://answers.ros.org/question/66012/removing-catkin-workspace/

---

Originally posted by [chilicheese](https://answers.ros.org/users/43979/chilicheese/) with karma: 41 on 2019-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0